# How to test if a hook with certain label exists

Tags: hooks, lthooks

The `lthooks` documentation says:

[image]

But how should one know in advance if the hook with this given label exists or not? In my package I wish to clear the code with a given label in a hook before adding new code with that label to ensure that the code added is not duplicate. How should I do this without triggering the warning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the text under the LaTeX2e interface `\RemoveFromHook` says:

> `\RemoveFromHook` should be used only when you know exactly what labels are in a hook. Typically this will be when some code gets added to a hook by a package, then later this code is removed by that same package. If you want to prevent the execution of code from another package, use the voids rule instead (see section 2.1.7).

Comment: Thanks, I see. So probably the simplest way is to inject some empty code with that label to ensure that the label does exist...

Comment: Or set a flag true when the hook label is added and false when removed.  It is your hook/label so it is up to you to keep track of it.